# Extract source code from .jar file

Tags: java, jar, java-me, decompiling

Is there a way to extract the source code from an executable .jar file (Java ME)?

Comment: But note that doing this may be illegal depending on whether you own the copyright to the jar, the country you live in and your purpose for doing it.

Comment: If it is open source, get the source from the developer.  Otherwise "Any compliance with the EULA will be appreciated".

Comment: Check procyon decompiler. Download it's jar to decompile jar files. I have given steps below

Answer (score 168):

Use [JD GUI](http://jd.benow.ca). Open the application, drag and drop your JAR file into it.

Comment: is there a way to get source code from .jar without JD GUI ?

Comment: @ZulqurnainJutt use as mentioned in @elachance's answer `jar xf filename.jar`

Comment: This is the best solution.

Answer (score 67):

You can extract a jar file with the command :

```
jar xf filename.jar
```

References : [Oracle's JAR documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jar.html)

Comment: This is equivalent to renaming `filename.jar` to `filename.jar.zip` and then just unzipping it.

Comment: This doesn't extract the source code. It extracts the compiled source code.

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey it does extract source code when the jar contains java files, e.g. jars with names typically ending in "-sources". It indeed does only extract .class files when the jar does not contain any java source files.

Answer (score 43):

I believe this can be done very easily. You can always extract the source files (Java files) of a jar file into a zip.

**Steps to get sources of a jar file as a zip :**

1. Download JAD from http://techieme.in/resources-needed/ and save it at any
      location on your system.
2. Drag and drop the jar for which you want the sources on the JAD.
   3  JAD UI will open with all the package structure in a tree format.
3. Click on File menu and select save jar sources.
4. It will save the sources as a zip with the same name as the jar.

Hope this helps.

The link is dead due to some reason so adding the link from where you can download the [JDGUI](http://techieme.in/resources-needed/)

Comment: @Nitesh... I will be posting the link hosted on my website... please download it from there

Comment: The version in the techieme link works beautifully, thank you!

Comment: After saving all sources, when I open the Java files, it shows all the lines as commented lines. Is there any setting to fix that?

Answer (score 39):

Your JAR may contain source and javadoc, in which case you can simply use `jar xf my.jar` to extract them.

Otherwise you can use a decompiler as mentioned in adarshr's answer:

> Use [JD GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/). Open the application, drag
>   and drop your JAR file into it.

Comment: Note that .jar files are actually .zip files and can be opened with any ZIP tool.

Answer (score 17):

I know it's an old question Still thought it would help someone

1) Go to your jar file's folder.

2) change it's extension to .zip.

3) You are good to go and can easily extract it by just double clicking it.

**Note:** I tested this in MAC, it works. Hopefully it will work on windows too.

Comment: @JCodex, I'm doing a research project on the sentiment analysis tool "opinionfinder" and its jar does indeed contain both java AND class files. so your comment is not 100% true. I know it would usually contain only .class but not in this case at least

Comment: Your solution will only extract .class files not the source code.

Comment: Seems JD-GUI is a multi-platform tool that actually decompiles the code and shows the source code for classes in all packages. I tried it and could get the source code in a second in MacOS. I have Java 8 installed . You can get it on http://jd.benow.ca
Not sure if it works for large projects.

Comment: need source code which is not provide by the way you described

Answer (score 11):

Do the following on your linux box where java works (if u like the terminal way of doing things)

```
    cd ~
    mkdir decompiled_code && cd decompiled_code
//  download jar procyon from https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yC2gJhmLoyE8royCph5dLEncgkNZXj58/view?usp=sharing
    java -jar procyon-decompiler-0.5.36.jar /Path/to/your/jar -o .
```

**NOTE** : as @Richard commented "this may be illegal depending on whether you own the copyright to the jar, the country you live in and your purpose for doing it."

Comment: For a specific class file you can do java -jar procyon-decompiler-0.5.36.jar /Path/to/your/jar package/of/the/java/class.class > className.java

Answer (score 6):

Steps to get sources of a jar file as a zip :

1. Download **JD-GUI** from http://java-decompiler.github.io/ and save it
   at any location on your system.
2. Drag and drop the jar or open **.jar** file for which you want the
   sources on the JD.
3. Java Decompiler will open with all the package structure in a tree
   format.
4. Click on File menu and select save jar sources. It will save
   the sources as a zip with the same name as the jar.

**Example:-**

[image]

We can use **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers** as well for update/extract code if require.

From eclipse chose Import **Jar**  and then select jar which you need. Follow instruction as per image below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AndroChef Java Decompiler produces very good code that you can use directly in your projects...

Answer (score -2):

Above tools extract the jar. Also there are certain other tools and commands to extract the jar.
But AFAIK you cant get the java code in case code has been obfuscated.

Comment: The greatest answer

Answer (score -6):

suppose your JAR file is in C:\Documents and Settings\mmeher\Desktop\jar and the JAR file name is xx.jar, then write the below two commands in command prompt:

1> cd C:\Documents and Settings\mmeher\Desktop\jar

2> jar xf xx.jar

Answer (score -9):

-Covert .jar file to .zip (In windows just change the extension)
-Unzip the .zip folder 
-You will get complete .java files

Comment: As a small note on this method... It is true that jar files are fancy zip files. However, unziping a jar will most likely yield *.class files, that is "compiled" java files. It is possible to "decompile" class files to normal java files. This functionality is included in many IDEs

Comment: this will just unlock class files