# Decompile .class File to .java File using Proycon

Tags: java, class, converters

I have a project that converts `.class` files to `.java` file, during the research I've found that **Proycon** is a java library that helps to do this. unfortunately I couldn't find any proper documentation for Proycon. anybody having experience using this, if yes please tell me which method I have to use for converting .class to .java file and to print it in to console?

Comment: Was the [home page with a wiki and the author's contact info](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon) not sufficient?

Comment: @JasonC I think my google couldn't find the link, do you have a link ?

Comment: Click the link in my comment... it's also the first Google result for "procyon decompiler".

Comment: @JasonC I have already read that, but it does not describe about decompilation methods

Comment: To anyone using Procyon, do feel free to contact me directly with any questions you may have.  I can be reached via BitBucket direct message, Twitter, or e-mail.  My contact info is on the Procyon BitBucket page.  I also check the `decompiler` and `decompiling` tags regularly on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `procyon-decompiler-0.5.30.jar` from its Bitbucket [repo](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/downloads/).

If you need to decompile one or more jars, please copy them to a folder and then run:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -jar c:\procyon\procyon-decompiler-0.5.30.jar -o . *.jar
```

In the above command I'm specifying the full path to the `procyon` jar, and the `-o .` sets the output to the current folder.

Lets say I want to check `sentry-logback-1.5.4.jar`, after running the above command I will end up in the working folder with the following structure:

```
sentry-logback-1.5.4.jar
[io]
  `-- [sentry]
          `-- [logback]
                 `-- SentryAppender.java
```

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58711972/5930500 for downloading the jar as it's no more available from Bitbucket repo

Answer (score 1):

JD-core-java https://github.com/nviennot/jd-core-java is a thin wrapper of jd-core. the readme file shows how to use it in your project.

```
/* Returns the source of SomeClass from compiled.jar as a String */
new jd.core.Decompiler.decompile("compiled.jar", "com/namespace/SomeClass.class");

/*
 * Returns the sources of all the classes in compiled.jar as a Map<String, String>
 * where the key is the class name (full path) and the value is the source
 */
new jd.core.Decompiler.decompile("compiled.jar");

/*
 * Returns the number of classes decompiled and saved into out_dir
 */
new jd.core.Decompiler.decompileToDir("compiled.jar", "out_dir");
```

Comment: I have implemented this method it caught an exception "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library"

Comment: This is due to some missing library.
refer to below link as a troubleshooting guide. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403788/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in-java-library-path

Comment: the problems is the given github source code is wrapper for linux, I am working in windows, do you have Windows wrapper ?

Answer (score 0):

Download [Java Decompiler(JD)](http://jd.benow.ca/) to convert .class file to to .java
i have used this Decompiler it is best in my opinion

Comment: @ShajeerAhmd yes i have

Comment: @Engineer can you mail it in to info4shajeer@gmail.com

Comment: @ShajeerAhmd yes why not

Comment: @ShajeerAhmd check your email i have sent it to you

Comment: @Engineer can you verify the sent e-mail once ,not reached yet

Comment: @ShajeerAhmd delevry status failed your email is incrrct please check and send again

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49047/discussion-between-shajeer-ahmd-and-enigneer)