# External jar's Source not found android eclipse

Tags: java, android

I am attaching and external jar in android project. Project properties > java build path > and external jar >. But  when i try to see the jar it shows like this.( see screen shot )

> [image]

Is this a normal thing or external jar always seems like this? The code is running fine but output is not as I expected. If there is a problem attaching this jar kindly guide me through ( How to make it perfect ).

Comment: Order and Export this external jar file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly see the source code from jar file. You can try the link given below:-

[Extract source code from .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107187/extract-source-code-from-jar-file)

may be it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

This seems alright, it does show up like this if you try and open up a referenced jar file, what is exactly the problem youre facing?

What i have noticed most times is that in addition to the steps that you have taken, you must also copy all the imported jar files in the "libs" folder under the project file.

Comment: I am trying to get push notification. Using this link http://www.push-notification.org/#doc. But when I try to send a notification using their server. It always shows device offline.