# Eclipse Java EE IDE not showing errors in basic Eclipse Project when *.java files imported via General > File System

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling, build

I downloaded the 64 bit Java EE IDE 64 bit version of Eclipse from this website today.  Looks to be the Luna Release (4.4.0) if that matters.  I can never figure out which version to download for my particular situation.

[image]

I then used JD GUI ([Extract source code from .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107187/extract-source-code-from-jar-file)) to get the source code from a jar file so I can fix the source code that's broken.  And then extracted the source code from the zip file in a personal folder under C:\ in Windows.

After launching Eclipse, I created a project under the default workspace location, called "test1" using the most basic project type (File > New > Project).  When I had a maven project in there before creating "test1", I had an errors panel that showed me build errors.  (I have "Build Automatically" turned on in Eclipse)  However, the errors panel is now gone.  I just have the "Project Explorer" and open files tabs panel showing.  I could not find how to open the errors panel.  Does anyone know?

I then went to File > Import > General > File System, to get a dialog called Import.  I chose the root folder of the extracted zip files (from the *.jar file).  I then clicked "Browse" to find "test1" project.  And then clicked finish.  It seems to have copied all of the files in that temp zip extraction location to the test1 location.

If I start typing invalid syntax, I get no build errors.  How can I see the Java build errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> using the most basic project type (File > New > Project).

The most basic project type has no functionality attached to it. Make it a Java project, instead. They you can configure just what's on its `Java Build Path`.

Comment: Interesting, once I created a new Project and chose "Java Project" from the top of the list, File > New > Java Project now shows up in the File > New sub-menu.  Before it did not.

Comment: So having a "Java Project" type, that now shows the "Problems" tab panel, the "Javadoc" tab panel and the "Declarations" tab panel in a single panel at the bottom by default.  However, it doesn't show an error if I make a syntax error in the code.  How do I get it to recognize the imported *.java files.  I tried saving the file after making an assignment statement using incorrect syntax.  That didn't do anything.

Comment: Okay, now I figured it out. After I do the import, I have to drag and drop all of the *.java files from the default import folder, into the "src" folder that was created. Then the errors start showing up like crazy!

Comment: I did it once more from the beginning. And when I clicked on "src" (to set focus there) before doing the import, everything was placed there automatically.