# Extract/open Jar file gives unreadable text

Tags: java, jar, decompiling

I have a .jar file and when I extract/open it and open any of the included classes files .class and it shows unreadable text as shown below. Anyone knows why? and how I can show its contents normally?

[image]

Comment: what kind of file did you try to open?

Comment: A jar file is not meant to be readable by humans, but readable by machines instead. Is your question that you want to decompile it to get a .java file?

Comment: @Stultuske I have a .jar file, I extracted it then many files and folders, some files are .class and when I try openeing any of them they look like in the screenshot

Comment: @Tak so, you opened a .class file and expected it to be readable text? do you know what a .class file is? It's the version of your code, compiled so it is readable for the computer. it should not be a (human) readable text

Comment: @Stultuske oh okay, so is there a way to make it readable? or to read the contents of the .jar file?

Comment: Two ways, only one guaranteed to give you the completely correct result: 1. ask the author for the code 2. decompile the .class files and hope for the best

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to extract source code from the jar please have a look at this question.

[Extract source code from .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107187/extract-source-code-from-jar-file)