# Gradle sync failed: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs']

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I cloned a Github project and apparently I have this error. Here is the full error:
Gradle sync failed: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpUh9.png)

Comment: does the libs directory exist in your project with the jar file?

Comment: @PrateekGupta yes, the directory is [project-app]>app>libs>*.jar

Comment: is the method implementation present in the jar then? verify this because the error highlights this

Comment: @PrateekGupta no, how can I fix this?

Comment: try to get source code from the jar file and verify. refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107187/extract-source-code-from-jar-file